# How to alphabetically sort lines by a letter that is not at the beginning?

Tags: sort

I need to alphabetically sort something like this

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=ABC "~foo" Youtube
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XYZ "~bar" Youtube
```

and etc. I need it to take the characters after that tilde and sort it that way, and not by the channel ID that it normally would. Would anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify, I need them sorted a-z and only "foo", "bar" parts (and not the `Youtube` tag), and uppercase/lowercase differences should be ignored and I only have to deal with english characters. So how it is expected to look is

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XYZ "~bar" Youtube
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=ABC "~foo" Youtube
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us how you expect this to be sorted. Do you only want to sort on `"foo"` or do you want to sort on `"foo" Youtube`? And what about capital letters? Should those be treated differently? And how about non-ASCII leters? Do you need to deal with things like `á` or `γ`? Please add a more complete example _and_ the sorted output you expect from it.

Comment: Note that the tilde is allowed as a character in URLs, sorting by what comes "after the tilde" may give unexpected results. Sorting by the second blank-separated field may be a better option, if you can assume it never contains blank characters. Otherwise, more information on that second filed is needed. E.g. is it always double quoted? Can it contain double quotes (excluding the enclosing ones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input from the question, the command

```
sort -t'~' -k2 inputfile
```

prints

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XYZ "~bar" Youtube
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=ABC "~foo" Youtube
```

see `man sort` or https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sort.html

**Edit** to consider new requirements added to the question:

The sort key will be everything after the tilde (`~`) character up to the end of the line or everything between the first and second tilde. That means the `Youtube` part will be included in the sort key. Of course this is only relevant when there is a pair of lines with the same `foo"` or `bar"` part.

To get case insensitive sorting you have to add option `-f`.